# How do add a certificate from a self-signed server to trusted certificates in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, certificate

I have a dedicated server with a wiki and want to secure it so nobody can read my articles by sniffing my pages.

I do not want to pay for a valid certificate so I created a self-signed certificate. But always when I access my page through HTTPS I get a SSL Error with the following message:

```
The site's security certificate is not trusted!
```

How can I manually add the certificate to my trusted certificates or prevent that message from showing?

This is my server and I trust the certificate as long as it does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring the certificate management interface from `Options / Preferences > Under the hood > Manage Certificates`.

Comment: This will mostly just add it to the local users store, not to the system / computer store! You'll get the problem again and again for each user! How to add to System store in windows, have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/370217

Answer (score 1):

For OS X, to do it from the command line:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -p ssl -d -r trustRoot -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain selfsigned.crt
```

If you don't have a .crt file (`selfsigned.crt` in this command) already to reference, view the cert in Chrome and drag it to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome v38 there is an experimental feature to autosave the certificates previously accepted.

See: chrome://flags/#remember-cert-error-decisions