# SSL self-signed certificate on client side

Tags: browser, ssl, certificate, https

When I create a SSL self-signed certificate.

1. If I don't add the .crt on the client side,  the browser (Chrome/Firefox) seems to download implicitly the .crt. Is it possible to prevent this ?
2. If I add the .crt within Chrome Trusted root store, I get the so-called "Your connection is not private" page. Is it normal ? Is there a way to avoid it ?

Comment: Adding the certificate to the operating system's certificate store allows indicates to Chrome that you trust the certificate, it is at that point, you shouldn't get an untrusted page.  The only reason you would still get an untrusted page is because there is some sort of certificate error with the certificate your trusting.  Why do you want to prevent the client's browser from downloading the certificate?

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/301918/how-do-add-a-certificate-from-a-self-signed-server-to-trusted-certificates-in-ch?rq=1)

Comment: Ok, I want to give the .crt only to some computer/people inside the intranet.

Comment: In order to do that you would need to only allow specific machines to access the server.  You can also on those machines specifically not trust the certificate, then configure the browser to explicitly allow trusted websites.

Comment: I think the OP is getting confused between server and client certs. In order to limit access from users it is possible to create a CA and create self-digned client keys+certs which The web server can be configured to recognise and limit traffic on.  This allows a single server to serve protected and unprotected content [without worring abou ips or login usernames or passwords]. He should google ”client side certificates” as this is not amenable to a SU question.